# When I do `vagrant provision`, what does it happen in my dev box?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, vagrantfile, chef-solo

I'm sure the answer is based on how my setup and etc… but I'd like to figure out what file gets called and such.  I'm using `vagrant-berkshelf` and `vagrant-omnibus` plugins.  `Berksfile` is empty, `Vagrantfile` is using `'ubuntu/trusty64'` and provisioner is chef.

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.run_list = []
end
```

The reason why I'm asking is because I can call `vagrant provision`, it runs successfully, but when I get in the box and call `chef-solo`, it fails.  So I'd like to understand how that works.

Answer (score 0):

Chef-Omnibus installs Chef into a different location than Vagrant's normal Chef provisioner. So it's there, it's just (apparently) not in your path.

Comment: Indeed, `vagrant-omnibus` seems to install chef on `/opt/chef` but it still fails even I run `chef-solo` under `/opt/chef`. Is there a way to find out the exact set of commands?